# How do I customise the gnome-shell commandline?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-session

I'm trying to create a new GNOME session that has some custom arguments to `gnome-shell` (specifically, creating a couple of virtual monitors).  But I'm having some strange difficulties.

I've started by creating `/usr/share/xsessions/immersed.desktop`.  This contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Immersed
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu with a VR desktop
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=immersed
TryExec=/usr/bin/gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-GDM-SessionRegisters=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-42
```

This is identical to `ubuntu.desktop` except the name and comment have changed and it specifies `--session=immersed` instead of `--session=ubuntu`.

Then I've created `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/immersed.session`.  This contains:

```
 [GNOME Session]
-Name=Ubuntu
+Name=Immersed
 # Must be in sync with gnome-session@ubuntu.target.d/ubuntu.session.conf drop-in
 RequiredComponents=org.gnome.Shell;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings;
```

The only change here is the name of the session.  But when I try to start this session from the login screen, the shell doesn't start - a couple of startup apps do start but there is no desktop, no panel, and the windows can't be resized or switched between.

What I'd like to do is change `org.gnome.Shell` to `immersed-shell` and add `/usr/share/applications/immersed-shell.desktop` as a copy of `org.gnome.Shell.desktop` but with the extra commandline arguments to create the virtual monitors.  But if even what I've done above doesn't work, I'm not seeing much hope for it.

What am I missing?

It looks like maybe I need to create a new systemd user session as well - if so, can someone point me to some documentation on how this works please?